# Why does English omit diacritics on foreign names?

Tags: orthography, typography, alphabet, diacritics

Why does English omit diacritics from foreign names that still use the Latin alphabet? For example, why are the Czech tennis player Tomáš Berdych, the Norwegian crime writer Jo Nesbø, or the Polish city of Łódź so often simply spelled as *Tomas Berdych, Jo Nesbo,* and *Lodz*?

Within their native languages these are often separate letters, and in the Netherlands they would always use these diacritics where possible. So what’s the reason that English often omits these?

Two examples:

- http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/tennis/31042458
- http://www.amazon.co.uk/Jo-Nesbo/e/B004MSFDCG/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1

(Note: I am only talking about names using the Latin alphabet, I am not talking about transliterated names)

Comment: Laziness, impatience, and ignorance. Sorry, but that's the reason.

Comment: Probably the same reason we spell it "Germany" instead of "Deutschland"; when foreign words are imported, they are often transformed, sometimes extensively. In the particular case of diacritics, the alphabet used in English lacks these (except in some old-fashioned and increasingly rare cases), to the extent that it's often not even obvious how to *type* such letters, outside of professional typesetting contexts. Where those contexts do prevail (e.g.  established news media), often a style guide will determine whether and where to use inflected letters in foreign names and words.

Comment: The letters á, š, ø, ł, ó, and ź are not part of the English alphabet. There’s no rule against using them in foreign words (I personally always write _złoty_ rather than _zloty_, for example), but there’s also no particular reason to use them in an English setting. I don’t really see how the script using in the source language is particularly relevant—you always have the option of including non-standard letters or not when writing in English. (Note: if you’re talking Norwegian, the letter _ø_ doesn’t have any diacritics. It’s a simple, uncompounded letter like _i_ or _f_.)

Comment: tchrist, agreed.  Most of us Brits grew up with a language that used no diacritics, and except when handwriting, had no way of forming them: our old typewriters, and earlier computers, had no way of composing accented letters.  Microsoft and Apple have partially rectified this, but it's still a messy business writing foreign text in an English-language environment.  Doesn't mean we shouldn't try!

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: Also, the Dutch do not “always use these diacritics when possible”. For example, the Dutch sports site sportuitslagen.org writes [_Tien Minh NGUYEN_](http://www.sportuitslagen.org/tien-minh-nguyen-badminton-spf74023.html) rather than _Nguyễn Tiến Minh_, and even De Telegraaf writes [_Lech Walesa_](http://www.telegraaf.nl/buitenland/20173476/__Lech_Walesa_uit_ziekenhuis__.html) rather than _Lech Wałęsa_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I find that we are more apt to do a fairly good job at Western European languages, but that we fall down on languages coming from anywhere east of there—the Slavic languages being notable problems for us and Vietnamese unthinkable. I try to always write *Karel Čapek* for the famed inventor of the robot, and *Ceaușescu* and *Mohorovičić* when I must. But most people aren’t able to [follow Bringhurst’s advice](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80397) even writing OED words. As an aside, I kinda wish the title of this posting had been *«Ẅɦƴ ðøñť ɏṏᶙ Эŋᵹɭıſɦɝȥ ẘȑịƭӭ ƃĕȶȶǝʁ‽»* :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I stand corrected that using foreign diacritics is common in The Netherlands: neither nu.nl as nos.nl uses them. They seem to use the accents that are common to the Dutch language though (like the grave and acute accent). So it looks like the Dutch are not much better than the Brits ;-)

Comment: @tchrist: In reference to your very first comment, I wouldn't think that institutions like the BBC would omit diacritics out of 'laziness, impatience, [or] ignorance'. They deliberately choose to ignore these diacritics, and I wonder why that is. It may not matter to the average Joe, but it does matter to people  like myself who have a grasp of those languages. To me, spelling Lech Wałęsa as Lech Walesa is akin to a spelling mistake. I recently read an English book on Polish family life, and the omission of diacritics really annoyed me (golabki just don't taste the same as gołąbki ;-))

Comment: The British policy about accents and foreign words is that British pronunciation and spelling is to be preferred in every case. Including speaking French fluently with a strong English accent, which irritates the hell out of the French, and has been policy for centuries because of that. The British royal family has spoken French since the Norman conquest, for instance, no matter what [Shakespeare said in _Henry V_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/henryv-notes.html).

Comment: @tchrist you missed the most important descriptors: indifference & disdain. We don't care how other languages spell their words, and we think it is strange if they expect us to :-)

Comment: Are speakers of other languages any different ?

Comment: @TallArnie But you must understand that English speaking countries have no clue about the difference between l and ł or a and ą. To other countries, the characters in question simply do not exist in the language. For fun, check out [habanero versus habañero](https://www.google.com/search?q=habanero+or+habañero) (versus jalapeño).

Comment: Duh!! They're not on the keyboard.

Comment: I've encountered computer programs (specifically a word processor and an email program) that allowed me to put an acute accent on an e but not on an n, and that allowed me to put a cedilla under a c but not under an s or a t.  So, as far as the designers of these programs are concerned, French is OK, but Polish and Romanian aren't. I suppose that, if I were less lazy, I could have found solutions to these, but I really did try in the case of Romanian. (And yes, I'm aware that the thing I want in Romanian isn't technically a cedilla, but, being lazy, I consider it close enough.)

Comment: There used to be a café in my home town calling itself the Continental Food Bar. This was written with a diaeresis (two dots) over every 'o' and 'a', presumably to give the phrase a 'foreign' appearance, but with no ides of changing the pronunciation. I never went in there, but I always mentally pronounced it with the vowel sounds appropriately modified!

Comment: Why don't literate English write Japanese using Japanese characters? How dare the English be so provincial!

Comment: @Mitch - Or Chinese?

Comment: We're no worse than anyone else. In certain respects better. We English refer to the (historic) French king as Louis, whereas the Germans call him Ludwig and refer to Shakespeare's play as Heinrich V. And East Europeans tend to add endings to English names to give them a gender that corresponds to the sex of the individual. (I enjoyed that last one.) And the French talk about an Austrian composer called Mozar. etc. etc.

Comment: As David says, it is simply incorrect to say that English speakers are lazy, or at least lazier than anyone else. See how many non-Spanish diacritics you find in a Spanish newspaper, or look at what Chinese or Japanese do with European words and names.

Answer (score 15):

I, an ignorant, ***lazy***, hubristic, and (most-importantly) ***impatient*** American, need to add this preface, so I will have enough letters for this to be counted as an answer.

---

One word:

## Keyboard

---

Please, before you take offense at my use of adjectives, read the second-to-last paragraph before the note about dıacrıtıcs ın English.

Now that I've made this answer longer anyway, I shall give some exposition. As an English-as-a-first-language American who has worked with diacritics and accent marks and slashed letters quite a bit, I give the explanation that **the US English keyboard (at least with the Windows default) contains no letters wıth dıacrıtıcs**, with the possible exception of the [tittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle)<sup>1</sup>.

Neither does the [United Kingdom keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg) have any *differentiating/distinguishing* diacritics, unless you use the `Alt Gr` key, but I'll just show the American, `<hubris>`because it's [American](https://youtu.be/6E9WU9TGrec?t=23)!`</hubris>` Check it out!

[image: United States Keyboard Layout]

([attribution](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=11391326) / [source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg))

Let's see it with the lower-case letters. (Note that there's no `Alt Gr` option for us default, ignorant American users of Windows.)

[image: US English Keyboard Layout with lowercase letters]

([source](https://images.anandtech.com/doci/6392/KB1.png))

Most <s>English-speakers</s> English-typers [sic] use only one keyboard layout. There are people such as I, who, for purposes including genealogy work, has a-dozen-or-so keyboard layouts set up on my computer.

Let's go through a stream of consciousness that I might have whilst using diacritics in genealogy: "*OK, Lithuanian, that means push `Ctrl`+`Shift` ... hmm ... seven times, then I have to hit `Caps Lock`. Now, push `Shift` ... umm ... it's above the ... `3`? No ... `4`? No ... `5`? No ... `6`? There it is!*" On my computer screen pops us an Š, and I can write the place-name, **[Šiauliai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0iauliai)**.

Most who do have extra keyboard layouts aren't as OCD as I am. Let's say that I want to talk about a couple of composers. Back to my thoughts: "*Oh, shoot, I don't have Czech set up on my computer. Time for Google Translate. Choose to translate from Czech. Click the drop-down keyboard. Who cares what I translate to ...*" Some typing and then copy ... Go back to my document about music and money and paste the name, **[Leoš Janáček](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo%C5%A1_Jan%C3%A1%C4%8Dek)**. Back to my train of thought, "*Shoot, I can't find the u with a circle over it. (Note to future self, it's where the American English keyboard has a semicolon.) Forget that, I'm heading to Wikipedia. Type the name - yes, without diacritics ... There he is! Copy, paste. Boom!*" Hooray, now we have **[Bohuslav Martinů](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohuslav_Martin%C5%AF)** on the page. "*Okay, most everything uses `Alt Gr`+`E` for Euro. Good. Shoot! Where's the percent symbol? Dang, I switched back into French instead of English...*"

I hope I've illustrated a bit the reason why we [lazy, impatient, and ignorant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224432/why-does-english-omit-diacritics-on-foreign-names#comment478760_224432) (@tchrist♦) as well as [hubris](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/224553/300794)-ful (@hunterhogan) ***American*** English speakers don't use diacritics.

By the way, I have no arguments with those characterizations for Americans, but I won't claim them for the Brits. (It's all in good fun, friends, no offense taken or meant.)

If you'll excuse me, I'm going to read [this site, entitled *Orthographic diacritics and multilingual computing*](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/dia/diacritics-revised.htm), while listening to some [Fryderyk Franciszek Chopin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Chopin), - the Polish version, so I don't have to use those funny ink splotches that one often sees near the letters of his name, or that "Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric Fran%C3%A7ois Chopin" version ... dang (verb version of "dang") his French father who moved to Poland and then sent his prodigious, 21-year-old son back to Paris ... It's as if he didn't foresee English-speakers from around the world discussing his son on the keyboard-layout-dependent Internet ...

---

**Note 1:** **Dıacrıtıcs ın English**

There is the [tittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle), which I, as well as [others](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96417/300794), *do* consider a diacritic. However, as was well stated in Evertz, Martin, *[Visual Prosody: The Graphemic Foot in English and German](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/dia/diacritics-revised.htm)*, Walter de Gruyter GmbH & Co KG, Jun 25, 2018, p.43,

> The dots in `<`i, j`>`[,] ... in contrast to other diacritics, ... *do not bear any function* [and] do not even distinguish letters from each other in the writing system under consideration.

The emphasis is mine. [Opposing argument link.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96406/if-a-tittle-sits-atop-an-i-or-a-j-%C4%B1-or-%C8%B7-then-where-do-jots-sit#comment196442_96417) ... [My rant, which @ChrisH correctly pointed out was extraneous. (Sorry, I got excited.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m126E.jpg)

Comment: +1 for perl content :) But you seriously need a Mac, where it’s a lot easier to do all that.

Comment: Honestly, I think you have a good answer in here which is ruined by the fact it's embedded in a rant where you argue with nobody in particular about whether or not the dots on *i* and *j* are diacritics.

Comment: Point well-taken @ChrisH. I'll cut that out now.

Comment: @tchrist♦ , you have an excellent point. However, I couldn't have made my point as well if I were using a Mac (or Linux.) I actually had to get my Windows Laptop out to remember the hard way of doing stuff, so I could write out my streams of consciousness. Also, I need to thank you for your "Sorry, but that's the reason," comment to the OP, partly because it contains a lot of truth, and partly because it made it a lot of fun to write this answer.

Comment: Cute, but it really goes back to the need to meet deadlines in the era of manual typesetting. Everything else is just inertia in the educational system.

Comment: @Spencer, nice work in going back for the historical base of the problem.

Comment: Regarding the tittle I'd say it makes a difference in "naive" compared to "naïve". But then, so would no tittle versus one. Anywho, if you ever feel the keyboard layout isn't enough, there's always MSKLC for Windows and multiple options for Linux. No idea about Mac. On Android and iOS a long press on the respective key suffices to tickle out the diacritics. I for one use my own keyboard layout and can effortlessly type ążęćśðſᵹïłöäøæåμüßóíúýéƿ and a number of other characters (not just letters with diacritics) **on a US keyboard**.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is obvious: Modern Standard English does not have diacritics. Why would you expect English copy to include non-English characters? If someone wants to write my English name in a non-English language I expect the writer to do just that, and I don't complain if my name looks different when written in that language.

Comment: Well, except that you do see diacritics in English writing. Do you turn in a *resume* or a *résumé* with your job application? Some use the former, some the latter.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in comments, since the diacritical markings (and crossed-letter letters) don't (generally and currently) have an analog in English language, the markings will be ignored for the common English speaker who will make a best guess at what the characters resemble from A-Z and what they sound like from their closest A-Z analog.

To an English speaker, the closest thing that is learned in school to a diacritical marking is an apostrophe used as a stressed syllable indicator, and (IPA aside) the "long vowel" marking (āēīōū) or "short vowel" marking (ăĕĭŏŭ). And those are pronunciation guides, not spelling guides.

Comment: Some English speakers may be familiar with the diaeresis used in words such as coöperate.  It does have a distinctly old-fashioned feel, though.

Comment: @BrianTung ... or [a potentially metal-like taste ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut)

Answer (score 5):

I think it is an attempt to appropriate the word (into English), and I believe it is quite common (in the sense that this is what language users do and will do).

For example, the name of the German town of Meißen was -- as far as I'm aware -- always spelled 'Meissen' outside Germany. This is the same phenomenon.

One might take the view that a word is more than just its spelling, and consequently, spelling is not all-important. In case, for example, there is a spelling in the target language that better approximates the pronunciation in the source language, the new spelling is often used. This is not the case here; the problem here is that there's no easy way to render, or approximate, the pronunciation.

It is quite difficult to do full justice to a foreign word or two within a phrase, pronunciation-wise. Ignorance put aside, a mighty reason for this is the different [articulation basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_of_articulation) for the source vs. the target language. At best, there's a slight stammer, at worst, it's a farce.

Anyway, we Czechs counter the humiliation of being deprived of our diacritics by maiming  foreign proper names in our own fashion, often beyond recognition. Thus 'Paris' becomes 'Paříž'; 'London' becomes 'Londýn' and 'in London' becomes 'v Londýně' (locative); 'Serena Williams' becomes 'Serena Williamsová' (female surname, nominative). (To abide by tennis players...)

Comment: How would the Czechs write Lech Wałęsa, as neither of these diacritics are used in Czech?

Comment: In established media, books etc., as you do. Pending availability of the diacritics also elsewhere. But even with Polish, which is quite close to Czech, the major problem is not how to spell it correctly but how to read the word from its (correct) spelling.

Comment: That'll teach us arrogant non-Czechs.

(On a serious note - great answer.)

Comment: @anemone But Meissen would be fine to use in German as well (substituting the ss for ß). It would not be ideal, but okay. In all-uppercase scenarios this would be the normal case, even though a [capital ß has been introduced (ẞ)](https://unicode-table.com/en/1E9E/). It's the same with Strasse (street) which used to be spelled with ß - Straße - before the several spelling reforms and re-reforms of the past 30 or so years.

Answer (score 5):

In a note appended to the question, the OP says 'I am only talking about names using the Latin alphabet, I am not talking about transliterated names'. This implies that the OP regards it as unproblematic that Japanese, Russian, Israeli, or Greek names appear in English contexts in a form that is different, sometimes vastly different, from the original. What the OP perceives as the problem is supposed to be somehow created by the fact that English uses the *same* alphabet as Danish, Czech, or Polish.

In some sense it is true that these languages use the same, that is Latin alphabet. However, looked at in another way, the alphabets they use are not quite the same: if they were exactly the same, there would be no problem. One can thus think of English alphabet as, in a way, different from (although similar to), say, Polish or Danish alphabets. If one takes that stance, the fact that Polish and Danish names change their form when they appear in an English context, can be thought of as transliteration. It is not clear why transliterating names from a similar alphabet, such as Polish, would be any more problematic than transliterating names from a less similar one, such as Greek.

This answer articulates the argument that was, in a more casual way, already made in the comments by Dan Bron, Janus Bahs Jacquet, and Mitch.

Comment: Also the Turkish 'ı' which is the roman 'i' missing the tittle. What about the Icelandic thorn 'þ'. All these foreign diacritics are _foreign_ in English, and therefore very rare. The argument should be in the other direction - why should any typesetting system for print media (in _any_ language script) spend resources on foreignisms? (of course Unicode reduces the problem considerably and we should be seeing more non-English letterforms.

Comment: There is probably a good reason for a writer to take the trouble to follow the original spelling when writing for an audience that is sufficiently bilingual to be able to make sense of the non-English symbols. But it is indeed unclear what is supposed to be the point of doing so when one knows that one's readers have no idea what  to do with them. It should thus not be surprising if, say, Turkish names are handled differently in general-circulation newspapers than in scholarly books on Turkish history that are written for specialists in that field.

Comment: I think this approach is very valuable, i.e. the idea that, each time we use a name that was originally used in a language other than that which we are speaking, we can consider composed from a different alphabet. It's like learning the ABCs (or aąbcćs or АБВs) for different languages. I think most of ah bay say in the Spanish alphabet with its extra ñ. All these alphabets have at their base the Latin (Roman) alphabet with added diacritics and other marks (such as the with-a-stroke mark.) However, I think it a great statement that they are different alphabets, if only because of pronunciation.

Comment: There are so many shades of this. Given your example of Danish vs. Polish think of Pelle vs. Paweł. Same name. Derived from the same root. Spelled and pronounced differently in either language. And in German history books you'll find Charlemagne (that is: Charles the Great) written as Karl der Große. The thing, however, is that transliteration usually attempts to keep the pronunciation close enough. Take Russian Ж which is usually transliterated into English as Zh. The same should be done for Polish ż then. So my point: transliteration is not mere removal of diacritics.

Answer (score 4):

Broadly agree with @tchrist (lazy, impatient, ignorant).  I would add as well, however, that English speakers are extremely comfortable with impenetrable and unfathomable pronunciation differences.  Memorising an enormous variety of irregular pronunciation is part of what we are used to doing.  As such, we don't expect to be given guidance on pronunciation from the page, and diacritics almost get in the way of having a good 'run up' to a word (and if you're lucky enough to have heard it spoken, trying to recall how it sounded) !

Comment: I doubt most native English-speakers would allow diacritics to really affect their pronunciation of a foreign word. Most people seeing the name _Łódź_ would probably pronounce it [lɒʣ] whether it had diacritics or not, whereas the Polish (and presumably thus more ‘correct’) pronunciation is [wuʥ], more or less like ‘woodge’ would be pronounced in English.

Comment: [Very closely related](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80397).

Comment: Hmm.  It's an interesting question.  I reckon most native English speakers are seriously put off by diacritics, even grave and acute accents (which they most likely ignore - unless they also speak the language in question).  If the diacritic is not there to confuse matters the standard approach to learning a new word can more easily take place (ie compare to similar letter combination and have a go).  Usually the result is an anglified mangulation. I suppose the point is that English is not, and never will be as simple and clear to pronounce as, say, Spanish.

Comment: I believe you are referring to Diplodocus?

Comment: Au contraire mon ami, it is diacritics that require memorizing pronunciations. We are content to guess, and we abide abominable guesses gallantly.

Comment: I've just come across this BBC article which put me in mind of this discussion, and the hopelessness of trying to notate the spoken English word (and 'diplodocus' doesn't even have diacritics) bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-magazine-monitor-31040334

Comment: It's a common trope in English character comedy for someone to be prone to pronounce words as they are written, indicating to the audience that they have only read them in books, not heard them in conversation, indicating a great deal about class and education. That this idea seems rare in other European languages, I think that illustrates that the letters used are only guidelines to pronunciation, even in native English words. As Dan suggests, when a foreign word comes along we use the letters at hand as they are merely aide memoir as to the word itself.

Comment: I've been a couchsurfing host in Iceland to a number of US guests and I can confirm what Janus said. Not a single one of them made an attempt to pronounce the Icelandic place names properly. May not sound like a big deal, but when you're asking for directions while touring the country it can make all the difference. Guests from the UK and elsewhere were actually trying, at least.

Answer (score 4):

One of your examples was from the BBC, so I attempted to find any mention of diacritics in the [BBC Style Guide](http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/journalism/news-style-guide), but I could not find anything.

I did find an incredible page on Wikipedia that is not an article, but is rather a User Page, and it has [an unbelievably detailed explanation of diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Prolog/Diacritical_marks), including recommended usages from most major style guides and many specialized style guides.

In short, the consensus of professional editors is to preserve diacritical marks. The [Columbia Journalism Review](http://www.cjr.org/language_corner/language_corner_060914.php) has a short article that adds a little more clarity: use the diacritical marks as found in contemporary English language dictionaries.

### Why not use diacritical marks?

A few verifiable reasons were offered:

1. You are directly **quoting a source** and the source did not use the marks
2. English has fully **assimilated the word** without the marks (see CJR's advice, "use the dictionary")
3. For proper nouns, there is an established **Anglicized version** (my favorite example was Napoléon vs Napoleon)
4. The Associated Press is a notable dissenter and their reason is pragmatic: "Do not use them; they cause garbled copy in **some newspaper computers**."
5. **Habit**

### My completely unsupported opinion

I believe that a significant reason why most writers in English, especially native speakers of English, do not preserve diacritical marks is simple: **hubris**. For a couple hundred years now, the British Empire and then the United States empire have dominated multiple aspects of public life. The dominance of the USA is unprecedented. The USA is either the undisputed heavyweight or a significant player in nearly every sphere of public life: armed conflict; politics; film, music, television, and prose, hence language; capital; education; immigration; and possibly more. The only area that I can think of that the USA does not dominate is religion.

To this near-universal dominance, add the geographic isolation of the USA and add the fact that compared to equally developed countries, citizens of the USA are shockingly mono-lingual, and I believe the inevitable result is the general attitude, "I am right because I am American." (Please note that most citizens of the USA call themselves American and bristle at the suggestion that anyone from Latin America is also American.)

### Conclusion

There seems to be a gap between suggested usage by the majority of style guides and the majority of native-English writers, but most people who have considered the issue suggest using the diacritical marks.

Comment: I completely agree. In the case of proper nouns, omitting the diacritic in journalism may well lead to a case of mistaken identity. Here the BBC is lowering the bar on accuracy. Unlike places, the names of people should not be Anglicized, except in the case where the alphabet is completely different (e.g. Cyrillic) or perhaps the name of the person is internationally recognized (e.g. Napoleon) and the context is unlikely to be mistaken. It's likely that the diacritic is unseen by most English readers because they consider these marks nothing more than visual garnish.

Comment: Why has no one addressed the simple fact that US keyboards do not have diacritics, and most users (justifiably, since the need is so rare) don't know the key combinations to make them.

Comment: I didn't expand on reason #5 Habit, but part of the habit is because keyboards prior to computers could not make the marks, and computers can make the marks, but it is not simple. The lack of simplicity, however, is in my opinion, another example of American-English hubris. I support this claim by pointing to a program called Microsoft Maren. It is an ingenious, beautiful, simple, and free program for writing Arabic text using a Latin-based keyboard. If English writers wanted easy marks, it would be simplistic to provide them. Notice the deafening lack of demand for easy diacritics.

Comment: hubris? Why attribute to pride what could more easily be attributed to ignorance?

Comment: "Hubris often indicates a loss of contact with reality and an overestimation of one's own competence, accomplishments or capabilities." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubris Hubris is a form of ignorance.

Comment: @HunterHogan - How is "the lack of simplicity" another example of "American-English hubris"?  Fact of the matter is, the keyboard *is* simple, by design, and changing US keyboards to look more like French ones would only add complexity that 99% of users have no need for.  It's only those in the literary and journalism professions that would need the characters, and even then it's a small subset of those.  What I'm seeing here is a "holier than thou" attitude because "Nayh nayh nayn -- I use diacritics and you don't!"

Comment: @HotLicks - I agree that it may not be straightforward to type a letter with diacritics on a standard keyboard. But that cannot be an excuse/argument for a leading institution like the BBC or the Guardian newspaper.

Comment: Overestimating one's competence would only apply if one said,  "Don't tell me how to pronounce / spell your name. I got this."  It doesn't apply to, "What the heck does a dangly bit on the letter a mean? We ain't learnt that in the Alphabet Song."

Comment: @TallArnie it's not just the people who write that matters, it is also those that read it. So, now that the Internet is all global and stuff some random group of people will claim inverse superiority complex (It's not my hubris. I'm right. It's theirs! Their wrong, and not just wrong because of didn't know better, but intentionally being wrong because they think they know better.) Meanwhile, there's this large swath of people who read an English source, expecting English letters, and can't *literally* (and I mean literally, literally) parse the diacritical markings into something legible.

Comment: It is still legible--at worst, the reader cannot properly pronounce the word. Without the marks, the reader cannot properly pronounce the word either. The alleged keyboard problem and the alleged problem with reading are both addressed at length in the link from my answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Prolog/Diacritical_marks

Comment: Ignorance, indifference and a dose of post-imperial arrogance would be my assessment.  As a local example, I program multi-lingual documents for a London distributor, and insist on proper diacritics [as well as using a decimal comma for the European mainland].  But a lot of my colleagues think I'm being picky and over-accommodating of foreign ways.

Comment: @TallArnie, when I read your comment, I flew downstairs to check today's Guardian, thereby to defend it.  Eventually, I found accented letters in the Film Review section.  However ... I'd checked thru the whole main paper before I got there, because there was so little foreign news [except USA, and Greek, Russian, and Arabic which was transliterated anyway] that the matter didn't arise.  Which is a different problem, not belonging on this site!

Comment: Just spotted in the April 2014 edition of the New Yorker: "preëxisting" [which I'd spell "pre-existing"].  This is new to me (a Brit).  Can anyone in the USA tell me whether this is usual?  [I don't think this qualifies as a real question, so I'm posting it as a comment.]

Comment: I hadn't noticed until yesterday, but most street signs in Mexico do not use diacritics, which is fascinating to me. I have no idea why we don't use them. I read a linguist one time who said something like, "commonly used words tend towards diminutive forms." Maybe language in general tends towards simplicity, so dropping diacritics might be a natural change in language.

Comment: @DavidGarner: I guess the sports section may have some foreign names, like Tomáš Berdych, because of the Australian Open.
My original question also came about when I was reading this article in the Guardian this week (http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/dec/18/nazi-architecture-germany-property-rugen-past). In the first paragraph alone, why have Rügen and Führer been correctly spelled with an Umlaut whilst they leave off the accent from Cancún?

Comment: ... and to continue with the New Yorker: in the same edition, I also found "reëlection", but "medieval", where a diaeresis, really would be useful, to emphasize that it's "medi-eval".

Comment: @HotLicks: My early-1990s Macintosh keyboard didn't have diacritics either, but the default key mapping makes it reasonable to type them.  For some reason I cannot fathom, the only US keyboard layout choices that come stock with Windows either provide no practical means of typing non-ASCII characters or else turn some ASCII characters into dead keys (rather than e.g. saying that AltGr-Shift-Apostrophe is a dead key, but Shift-Apostrophe without AltGr is simply a quote mark).

Comment: @DavidGarner   I recall not too long ago when a well-educated British _linguist_ (who would brag about having learned Mongolian the previous week) telling me that my attempts to put umlauts on German words was "pedantic". And someone else (presumably French Canadian)  complained that the umlauts wouldn't render in his "French browser".

Answer (score 1):

Any author should consider his audience. Thus a scholarly book would use all the diacritical marks, etc. A book aimed at the popular press or the general reading public should stay away from them and render them in English (or American). For example, I am writing a book which includes a section on the architecture of early human dwellings of the Neolithic Age. I must necessarily must discuss early ruins and city sites in Turkey and Iran. For my readers, I believe that use of diacritical accents and letters would disrupt the reading flow as the reader's eye stops at the word with diacritics. Either that or the simply skip over the word, which makes it useless.