# What poetic device describes describes two (nearly) identical words together?

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-techniques

Examples I could think of:

- achieve achievement
- traditional traditions
- work of work

Would this be classified as a pun even if the subject isn't humorous? If not, how do I describe this word play?

Comment: The only thing is alliteration, the repetition of an initial sound. As for the words being like you say, there is no name for that, afaik.

Comment: Compare https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/pairs-in-common-idioms-phrases/7193#7193

Comment: _Achieve achievement_ (whatever it might mean) is, like _walk the walk, talk the talk, write the writing, say the saying,_ and many more, what is technically called a Cognate Object, where the verb has a form of itself as its object. Such a construction adds no information, but it stylistically emphasizes the action. The other two examples I don't understand at all; certainly there is no special term for them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of tautolgy:

OED

> **tautology,** n. **1. Unnecessary repetition, usually in close proximity, of the same word, phrase, idea, argument, etc.** Now typically: the saying of the same thing twice in different words (e.g. ‘they arrived one after the other in succession’), generally considered to be a fault of style.

It is permissible in poetry by virtue of, or as an example of **poetic licence** =

OED

**Licence**

> **4. Deviation from recognized form or rule, indulged in by a writer or artist for the sake of effect; an instance of this.** Frequent in phrase poetic (poetical, etc.) licence.